# Share links without spaces JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an app on React (Next.JS) where you can share articles. So the idea is that when you open an article, you can share it with friends on Twitter. So, imagine that I have this URL: 
https://mywebsite.com/article?id=U2FsdGVkX1+syiKZnBMYjzVP8Mey2ZYAGc7

Well, I'm using Next Router to get the current route and share it. Something like this:

```
const router = useRouter();
const id = router.asPath();
const share = `https://mywebsite.com${id}`
```

So with that, I get the URL as I put at the top of the question. Then, I put the 'share' constant on a `<a>` tag, like this:

```
<a href={`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${share}`} target="_blank">Share on Twitter</a>
```

But here is the problem, when you open the link, the '+' are replaced by spaces. Just like in the next pic:
[image]
This not only happens on twitter, but also on other social networks.
Hope you can help me! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode the full site URL as a query parameter to the Twitter URL.

Here's the most semantically clean way to do it:

```js
const siteUrlStr = 'https://mywebsite.com/article?id=U2FsdGVkX1+syiKZnBMYjzVP8Mey2ZYAGc7'

const twitterUrl = new URL('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet')

twitterUrl.search = new URLSearchParams({ text: siteUrlStr }).toString()

const twitterUrlStr = twitterUrl.toString()
// https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=https%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2Farticle%3Fid%3DU2FsdGVkX1%2BsyiKZnBMYjzVP8Mey2ZYAGc7
```

Or, for legacy browser support:

```js
const siteUrlStr = 'https://mywebsite.com/article?id=U2FsdGVkX1+syiKZnBMYjzVP8Mey2ZYAGc7'

const encoded = encodeURIComponent(siteUrlStr)

const twitterUrlStr = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${encoded}`
```